# How do I return when a column changes values from one month to the next in SQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have three different tables in SQL that represent months (jan, feb, mar). Each table has the same columns (ID, DATE, CSNA). An example for jan would be:

```
    ID        DATE         CSNA
1234770286  2/2/2023    Blue 10 A V 
1234770301  2/2/2023    Blue 10 C IV
1234770316  2/2/2023    Blue 10 B V 
1234770331  2/2/2023    Blue 5 A III
```

and an example for feb would be:

```
1234770286  2/2/2023    Red 10 A V 
1234770301  2/2/2023    Blue 10 C IV
1234770316  2/2/2023    Blue 10 B V 
1234770331  2/2/2023    Red 5 A III
```

The CSNA value sometimes changes from month to month, or it can stay the same. Also, some new rows may be added each month. I specifically want to find the rows and ID's where the CSNA value was changed from jan-feb and feb-mar. In the example, I'd want to return the first and last ID's (1234770286, 1234770331) since the CSNA data is different.

I tried running this query in mysql workbench to see changes from jan-feb:

```
SELECT *
FROM feb_data AS f, jan_data AS j
HAVING j.CSNA<>f.CSNA OR j.CSNA IS NULL
```

it seems to return more rows than are in either table and that is confusing me. I basically only want to return rows when the CSNA value is different from table 1 (jan) and table 2 (feb), and not bother showing rows when they are the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's `YEAR(CURDATE())`, the **ANSI-92** explicit JOIN syntax has been around for `(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1992) as A_Very_Long_Time`, it's long past time you adopted it. 
Bad Habits to Kick : [Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Can you edit your answer and add some simple data and the expected result

Answer (score 1):

the question is not entirely clear how these tables are related to each other, but I think it will help you solve the problem, or at least get closer to a solution.

```
select 
  * 
from 
  feb_data AS ff 
where 
  ff.id not in (
    SELECT 
      f.id 
    FROM 
      feb_data AS f, 
      jan_data AS j 
    where 
      j.CSNA = f.CSNA 
      and j.DATE = f.DATE 
      and j.CSNA IS NOT NULL
  ) 
  or ff.CSNA is null
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I used this code and it helped me realize I wasn't connecting the tables using the id's. I added j.ID = f.ID instead of j.date = f.date and got what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Seems we can join our tables by `id`, then we can do it using `INNER JOIN` as follows :

```
select j.ID, j.DATE as jan_date, f.DATE as feb_date, j.CSNA as jan_CSNA, f.CSNA as feb_CSNA
from jan_data j
inner join feb_data f on f.CSNA <> j.CSNA AND f.id = j.id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/sE89rkgc)

Comment: Thank you! My mistake was that I wasn't connecting the tables using id. Thanks for helping me realize.

Comment: @jpc31999 If this is the correct solution, you should select it.